# Flutter app is crashing on launch in AVD (before debugger connects) after importing stripe-payments library

Tags: android, flutter, dart, stripe-payments, android-virtual-device

Prior to adding the stripe_payment package to my app, I was able to build and run it using `flutter run` on an attached AVD (Pixel 2 XL spec, latest Android version). After adding it, the app won't install and start, and simply crashes on launch on the AVD. No messages are printed to the debugger or terminal, apart from the fact that the connection was terminated.

I have tried commenting out the import for the `stripe_payment` package, and the related lines of code, however, this doesn't fix the issue.

I have also tried running `flutter clean` and then attempted to build and run the app on the AVD, again to no avail (before and after the above lines were removed).

I am slightly at a loss as to what could be causing the issue.

I am importing the `stripe_payment` package like so:

```dart
import 'package:stripe_payment/stripe_payment.dart';
```

The main function looks like this. The public key is definitely correct and is being used in a separate web app.

```dart
void main() {
  StripeSource.setPublishableKey("pk_test_###########");
  SystemChrome.setPreferredOrientations([DeviceOrientation.portraitUp])
      .then((_) {
    runApp(new DemoApp());
  });
}
```

The package is listed in my pubspec.yaml as a dependency too:

```yaml
dependencies:
  flutter:
    sdk: flutter
  stripe_payment: any
```

Could simply having the stripe_payment library as a dependency be causing this issue, even if I am not making any calls to it? That seems a little odd, since it would make the package wholly unusable.

Comment: Have you tried embeding your first line in try/catch and printing exception if any.

Comment: Are you implementing FlutterFragmentActivity on your MainActivity (Android project)?